# Why does installing vzctl on a fresh Centos6.5-minimal break network connectivity?

Tags: networking, centos, iptables, openvz

I seem to have encountered a bug in vzctl's installation. Upon installing it in a clean CentOS6.5-minimal installation according to the official wiki, network connectivity is limited to pinging IP addresses (I suspect ICMP traffic only).

I have created a [bugreport](https://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2962) with steps to reproduce, also copied here:

1. Install node with CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso
2. `ifup eth0` and `ping google.com` to observe DNS resolution and network connectivity.
3. Install wget (`yum install wget`).
4. Follow steps on http://wiki.openvz.org/Quick_installation to install vzkernel, vzctl, vzquota, and ploop.
5. reboot
6. `ifup eth0` and `ping google.com` to observe NO DNS resolution and network connectivity.
7. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/openvz.conf` to `options nf_conntrack ip_conntrack_disable_ve0=0` and save.
8. reboot
9. `ifup eth0` and `ping google.com` to observe DNS resolution and network connectivity.

Note that disabling iptables via `service iptables stop` restores connectivity, but that is a 'suboptimal' (hum hum :P ) workaround.

This is the output from `iptables-save`:

```
# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Apr 30 12:50:00 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [110:16800]
:INPUT ACCEPT [107:15810]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [35:4954]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [35:4954]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 30 12:50:00 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Apr 30 12:50:00 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [35:4954]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 30 12:50:00 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

the conntrack paramater fixed it for me, but since you already have maybe you forgot these settings

## /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
kernel.sysrq = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
```

## reload

sysctl -p

I also had to settup a bridge, not sure if that has anything to do with it, but worth looking into!